# Яндекс-карта: не показывать балуны при открытии

Tags: webview, яндекс-карта-api, glide

Открываю яндекс карту в webview Glide apps
[https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?rtext=53.2643,34.4127~55.879829,38.290932](https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?rtext=53.2643,34.4127%7E55.879829,38.290932)
Открывается с открытым балуном
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] на маршруте.
Как отрывать без балуна?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее спасибо!